# Mobile Push Notification Service provider for D7

Tags: delphi, amazon-web-services, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Is there a major Mobile Push Notification service provider that supports Android, iOS and Windows Mobile and has Delphi or Pascal library (official, third party, or open source is fine)?  Simple HTTP API is also fine as I can use Synapse.

I've checked out Amazon AWS SNS Mobile Push but there's no official Delphi API for it.

The provider must not be a "startup" as I'm looking at a deployment that does not require changes to the API code (and my code) for at least 5 years.

Comment: You can use AWS SNS with HTTPS using Indy, which works on all mobile platforms with recent Delphi versions, and with Delphi 7 to communicate with the server API. But there can not be any Delphi API for mobile push notification services which works with Delphi 7 on the client side, because Delphi 7 does not compile for mobile platforms.

Comment: @mjn Yes, I'm referring to the server side. The JSON looks intimidating enough. For Client side, I'm using PhoneGap and Amazon AWS Javascript SDK.

Answer (score 1):

There is a cloud solution based on the popular RabbitMQ message broker:

**CloudAMQP - RabbitMQ as a Service** at http://www.cloudamqp.com/

It is available in multiple clouds (including AWS). [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) is a multi-protocol broker, and all CloudAMQP plans support the AMQP, AMQPS, HTTPS, STOMP and MQTT protocols.

AMQP, STOMP and MQTT use **message push**, with permanent or periodic connections to the server.

AMQP/STOMP/MQTT client libraries should be available for all major mobile platforms (see http://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html). For a comparision of protocols: [Choosing Your Messaging Protocol: AMQP, MQTT, or STOMP](http://blogs.vmware.com/vfabric/2013/02/choosing-your-messaging-protocol-amqp-mqtt-or-stomp.html).

The entry level plan with dedicated server (Big Bunny) supports around one million queued messages (if the devices are not connected, pending notifications wait on the server).

About queue resource usage:

> In RabbitMQ, queues are quite cheap. They're effectively lightweight
>   Erlang processes, and you can run tens to hundreds of thousands of
>   queues on a single commodity machine

(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7040605/80901)

*(I am a developer of STOMP message broker client libraries Delphi / Free Pascal for Windows and Linux)*

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm already using your Habari API + RabbitMQ + STOMP.JS/SOCK.JS to push to my PhoneGap application. But it only works if the user runs the app, so I'll need to find a mobile push notification provider. Thanks for your support. :)

Comment: the link for "Choosing your messaging protocol : AMQP, MQTT, or STOMP" https://blogs.vmware.com/vfabric/2013/02/choosing-your-messaging-protocol-amqp-mqtt-or-stomp.html is no longer active, any alternate links?

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran try https://web.archive.org/web/20160322044219/http://blogs.vmware.com/vfabric/2013/02/choosing-your-messaging-protocol-amqp-mqtt-or-stomp.html (found via https://stackoverflow.com/q/13377992/80901)